# Command View EVA Login Problem

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, hp

I'm using Command View EVA version 9.01 on a Windows Storage Server 2003 R2. And all of a sudden I can't log in to the command view, it always say incorrect username or password, I haven't done any change on the password nor the system. Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I'd be tempted to use this issue as an excuse to move to version 9.1 or 9.2 (might be a bit too new) - not only will you get all the benefits of upgrading but it might sort out your problem too. If not just uninstall and reinstall again, all the data is on the EVA/s anyway so you won't be losing much. Oh and have you tried changing your local account password then trying that again? God I love Command View but nobody posts any questions about it so thanks for feeding my storage-geekiness :)

Comment: Installing Command View is pretty simple.  Can see any harm in a "clean" upgrade.  I'd recommend populating the local groups "HP Storage Admins"and "HP Storage Users" with both local users _and_ domain users to help prevent lock-outs like the OP describes.

Comment: I see no harm in that approach at all.